# "OleDbException was unhandled...Syntax error in From clause"

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am getting this error saying

> OleDbException was unhandled...Syntax error in From clause

My code for login is given below.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Login

Dim con As New OleDbConnection
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim ds As New DataSet

Private Sub Login_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\Project work\anshu\fitness_0.1\Fitness.accdb"
End Sub
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btncancel.Click
    Me.Close()

End Sub

Private Sub btnlogin_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnlogin.Click


    If check() = True Then
        Main.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    Else
        MsgBox("Enter vailid Username and Password", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Login Validation Information")
    End If



End Sub

Public Function check()
    ds.Tables.Add(dt)
    con.Open()
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from User", con)
    da.Fill(dt) ---->here is the error!

    For Each DataRow In dt.Rows
        If txtname.Text = DataRow(1) And txtpass.Text = DataRow(2) Then
            con.Close()
            Return True

        End If
    Next
    con.Close()
    Return False

End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Q: So you're sure you have a table "User" in your "Fitness" MS-Access database?  Q: Have you tried that "select" from inside of Access to verify it works?

Answer (score 4):

User is a [reserved word](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321266) and must be bracketed:

```
"select * from [User]"
```